# Python,selenium, webdriver browser.get opens the browser, but script ends, i want it to wait till i close browser

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Below is my script, it works fine, but not to my requirement

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://somewebsite.com/')
#nextline of script
```

In the above example, it opens the browser and immedtly moves to next step.
i want the script to wait till i close the browser manually and move to next step
( as i want to login and download few files from server and move to next step)

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not a good idea to mix automated and manual control over selenium browser window. I'd automate these "login" and "download few files from server" parts too.

Comment: could you please give me a sample script of  logging into a https url link, and download specific file, i tried but no luck,  finally ended up with this, working script would be of great help. thanks :) @alecxe

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161444/python-selenium-webdriver-browser-get-opens-the-browser-but-script-ends-i-wan#comment48430438_30161444) that you generally should automate the whole process. However, there are cases where you may be writing "throwaway code" or a proof-of-concept where it might be advantageous to have manual control of part of the process. If I found myself in such a situation, I'd do something like this:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://google.com/')

try:
    while True:
        # This will fail when the browser is closed.
        browser.execute_script("")
        time.sleep(0.2)
# Setting such a wide exception handler is generally not advisable but
# I'm not convinced there is a definite set of exceptions that
# Selenium will stick to if it cannot contact the browser. And I'm not
# convinced the set cannot change from release to release.
except:
    has_quit = False
    while not has_quit:
        try:
            # This is to allow Selenium to run cleanup code.
            browser.quit()
            has_quit = True
        except:  # See comment above regarding such wide handlers...
            pass

# Continue with the script...
print "Whatever"
```

The call to `browser.quit()` is so that Selenium can cleanup after itself. It is very important for Firefox in particular because Selenium will create a bunch of temporary files which *can* fill up `/tmp` (on a Unix-type system, I don't know where Selenium puts the files on a Windows system) over time. In theory Selenium should be able to handle gracefully the case where the browser no longer exists by the time `browser.quit()` is called but I've found cases where an internal exception was not caught and `browser.quit()` would fail right away. (By the way, this supports my comment about the set of exceptions that Selenium can raise if the browser is dead being unclear: even Selenium does not know what exceptions Selenium can raise, which is why `browser.quit()` sometimes fails.) Repeating the call until it is successful seems to work.

Note that `browser` becomes effectively unusable as soon as you close the browser. You'll have to spawn a new browser if you wish to do more browserly things.

Also, it is not generally possible to distinguish between the user closing the browser and a browser crash.

Answer (score -1):

If the page is not fully loaded, you can always wait for a specific element on the page to show up, for example, your download button.
Or you can wait for all JavaScript to load.

```
wait.until( new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
            public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: thanks anton, but i think the above script will wait till the page to load fully and exit?  i want to exit after manually closing the browser

Comment: I understand you know. I can suggest you an approach. I'm not so good in Python but if I have to do it in C#, the approach will be as follows. Start the test in a new thread in an endless loop or something similar, assign the thread to new variable. The loop condition can check if the browser is opened or not if it is closed then exit.  Task taskA = Task.Run( () => Console.WriteLine("Hello from taskA."));
taskA.Wait();